# CloudFoundry Deployment with Bosh

Tags: cloud-foundry, vsphere, cf-bosh

I am trying to deploy cloud foundry with Bosh.

I am following this:
http://kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/from-zero-to-cloud-foundry-on-vsphere-part-3-deploy-cloud-foundry-with-bosh.html
and this
http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/vsphere/deploy_cf_vsphere.html

I am up to here:

```
bosh upload release releases/cf-189.yml
```

It goes for a long time, then I get a:

```
Uploading release
release.tgz:   100% |oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo|   3.5GB  20.3MB/s Time: 00:02:54

Director task 2
  Started extracting release > Extracting releaseHTTP 500: Internal server error
root@vm-cf-1:/bosh/releases#
```

I cant find any more info on it.  Any ideas please?

Comment: Get detailed task logs (`bosh task 2 --debug`) and job/application logs (target Micro BOSH, set deployment to that of your "full" BOSH, check out `bosh vms` to see what jobs and indices are running, and then fetch logs with `bosh logs <job> <index> --all`).  It can be quite a lot to sift through, you may need a little more back and forth help.  Check out the #bosh channel on freenode IRC.

Comment: Thanks, have not used IRC in years, tried, failed.  Will look again at IRC later.  This is my error:
tar: ./packages/dea_next.tgz: Wrote only 9728 of 10240 bytes
tar: ./packages/hm9000.tgz: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: ./packages/cloud_controller_ng.tgz: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: ./packages/postgres.tgz: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: ./packages/gorouter.tgz: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: ./packages/buildpack_python.tgz: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: ./packages/buildpack_java_offline.tgz: Cannot write: No space left on device

Comment: DO I need to provision my Director with more disk space?

Comment: Yes! It depends where the untarring is happening.  Make sure your director and/or workers have enough disk space to untar the full cf-release.

Comment: Easiest thing to do is use the freenode webchat client: https://webchat.freenode.net/.  Pick any nickname (ignore NickServ warnings if the name is taken), and and #bosh channel.  I'd never used IRC until yesterday, had to ask a question on the #bosh channel myself, freenode webchat was super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by adding additional resources to the director